# Boolean Mask Groupby Any and Create Indicator

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe in the following format:

```
id,criteria_1,criteria_2,criteria_3,criteria_4,criteria_5,criteria_6
1,0,0,95,179,1,1
1,0,0,97,185,NaN,1
1,1,2,92,120,1,1
2,0,0,27,0,1,NaN
2,1,2,90,179,1,1
2,2,5,111,200,1,1
3,1,2,91,175,1,1
3,0,8,90,27,NaN,NaN
3,0,0,22,0,NaN,NaN
```

I have the following program from [Python PANDAS: GroupBy First Transform Create Indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48118537/python-pandas-groupby-first-transform-create-indicator):

```
mask = (((df['criteria_1'] >=1.0) | (df['criteria_2'] >=2.0)) &
         (df['criteria_3'] >=90.0) &
         (df['criteria_4'] <=180.0) &
         ((df['criteria_5'].notnull()) & (df['criteria_6'].notnull())))

# reset_index() defaults to drop=False. It inserts the old index into the DF 
# as a new column named 'index'.
idx = df.reset_index()[mask].groupby('id').first().reset_index(drop=True)['index']

df['flag'] = df.index.isin(idx).astype(int)
```

However, now I would like to select for any rows where the conditions are met by group-not just the first.  It does not appear to be as easy as substituting .any() or .all() for .first().  Any troubleshooting tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mask` directly to extract all rows which meet your conditions:

```
df['flag'] = mask.astype(int)
```

Remember, that `mask` is just a series which returns, for each row, a Boolean value depending on whether all criteria are met.